# Overloading the ostream operator yields compile errors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hi all I have this code -

```
typedef struct signal_declairation{

  //these are for 2001 type declairation
  bool is_array;
  int array_start, array_end;
  PORT_ATTRIBUTE port_attribute; //port direction
  string port_type;              //logic, UDT, wire, accept every thing

  //this is common to 2001 and normal
  string port_name;

  //dumper method
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, signal_declairation &m_signal_declairation);


} SIGNAL_DECLAIRATION;

std::ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, signal_declairation &m_signal_declairation)
{
  string port_direction;
  switch(m_signal_declairation.port_attribute){
  case INPUT: port_direction = "input";
    break;
  case OUTPUT: port_direction = "output";
    break;
  case INOUT: port_direction = "inout";
    break;
  }

  if(m_signal_declairation.is_array==true){

    out << " Port Name = " << m_signal_declairation.port_name 
    << " Port Direction = " << m_signal_declairation.port_attribute
    << " Port type = " << m_signal_declairation.port_type
    << " This is an arrayed port :: Array Start = " << m_signal_declairation.array_start 
    << " Array End = " << m_signal_declairation.array_end ;



    }else{

    out << " Port Name = " << m_signal_declairation.port_name 
    << " Port Direction = " << m_signal_declairation.port_attribute
    << " Port type = " << m_signal_declairation.port_type;

  }

  return out;
}
```

When I try and compile, I get errors that look like this -

> parser_globals.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,
>   signal_declairation&)’: parser_globals.h:53:9: error: no match for
>   ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const char [14]’)
>        out << " Port Name = " << m_signal_declairation.port_name

Not sure why I am not able to pass class members to << as shown above. Can anyone help ????
Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had provided the complete error messages that you get and not just a small snippet, things would have been easier.

Based on what you provided so far, it looks like you might have forgot to include the necessary header(s) for the standard streams, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
```

This would cause the compiler to not find the `operator<<` overloads for the base types or the types from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

change your  overload  definition  :

```
std::ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, signal_declairation &m_signal_declairation)
```

by  `std::ostream& operator<< (ostream &out,const signal_declairation &m_signal_declairation) .`

Dont  forget  the  prototype too.

Comment: I tried as suggested, still get the same errors...any other thoughts / suggestions ??

Comment: 1. Define  your friend overload  function directly  in  your  struct/class,  dont' use  prototype.

Comment: The second parameter should be `const` for const-correctness, but the lack of `const` in this case cannot cause the error he's seeing. Also, the overload is defined correctly, making it a class member instead of a friend will not fix the error. As you can see in the error message, the compiler finds the overload, the error happens inside his overload.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about the ‘const char [14]’) out << " Port Name = ". It looks like the compiler cannot see the " Port Name - " as string, rather it sees it as character array. Have you include ?

Comment: Simon, the problem was that I forgot to include <iostream>